# Using typescript module without require()

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, vue.js

I write a typescript 2.3 app.ts which needs Vuejs library v2.
Vuejs script src is added manually in html file.
I just want use Vuejs with type checking !
I expected i just have to reference like this :

> /// < reference path="vue.d.ts" />

But the *Vue* class is not accessible from app.ts.

I tried to import the module directly :

> import * as Vue from "./vue";

This time i have to use *new Vue.Vue({})* to access to the class but VS 2017 build.
The app.js generated starts with *var Vue = require("./vue");*.
However in the browser, i got some errors :

- exports reference (solved by adding *export = 0;* at line 1 in .ts
- require is not a function

For require(), i add *< script src="Scripts/require.js">< /script>* but new error: *has not been loaded yet for context*.

I tried with systemjs instead of require.js, i add *< script>System.import('scripts/app.js');< /script>* i get a 404 accessing to "Scripts/vue" (the require from the app.js), the rest of app.js is not executed.

Note : i don't use tsconfig.json

I'm surprised cause in my memory, the reference of jQuery worked with typescript 0.9

I'm completely lost. Help me ! Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

I typically work around the issue you ran into by creating `globals.d.ts` file which is responsible to setting up the global environment that my code expects. In your case something like:

```
import * as _Vue from "vue";

declare global {
    const Vue: typeof _Vue;
}
```

This makes it so that the compiler will see a `Vue` symbol in the global space which is of the same type as what the "vue" module exports.

With the above file, this compiles:

```
const q = new Vue();
```

Note that you either will have to use a `tsconfig.json`. Even an empty one works. (By "empty", I mean a file that contains only an empty JSON structure: `{}`.) Or you will have to list all files to compile, including `globals.d.ts` at the command line.

Comment: I like this approch.`const q=new Vue()` doesnt build but `new Vue.Vue` does and I have intellisense.
That makes a problem : the generated JS file keep `Vue.Vue` notation which is incorrect (_file2.ts:10 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.Vue is not a constructor_).